# What to download in visual studio to create UML diagram

Tags: visual-studio-2017, uml

I'm a C++ beginner, and usually use DevC++.I need to create a UML diagram and I am trying to use visual studio. In videos that I have seen online I notice that they use templates from the C# library to access modeling projects such as UML diagrams. Does anyone know the extension that I'm supposed to download for this? Some options include SteelToe.net and ASP.net (in case I'm not using the proper terminology for the downloads available in C# template). Or does anyone know any good free websites to create UML diagrams in?

I tried downloading the React Core boilerplate extension because in the description it said TypeScript, and I saw that in one of the videos. However, it would not even open for me.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Visual Studio 2017, the UML Designers have been removed from Visual Studio. For more information, see [Microsoft's Documentation site](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/visualstudio/modeling/create-uml-modeling-projects-and-diagrams?view=vs-2019) and [Microsoft's Developer Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/uml-designers-have-been-removed-layer-designer-now-supports-live-architectural-analysis/).

What exactly do you need to model and why? There is a hell of tools but it is hard to recommend any without specification of your needs.

Comment: I was making a class diagram, I ended up using visual paradigm

Answer (score 2):

use Visio - a lot of UML templates and images.

option1:
https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/examples/uml_diagram_tool?a=1

option2:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jebbs.plantuml

option 3.
https://www.visual-paradigm.com

depends what type of UML you want to create.

Comment: I ended up using visual paradigm, thank you so much for the help!